# sbt "Conflicting cross-version suffixes" error with Spark using elasticsearch-hadoop

Tags: scala, sbt

I have an sbt project with several submodules. I am using Spark and recently trying to upgrade to Spark 2.0.0, which requires Scala 2.11 instead of Scala 2.10. Here are my sbt configurations:

`project/commons.scala`:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object Commons {
  val appVersion = "0.0.2"

  val settings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
    version := appVersion,
    scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
    resolvers += Opts.resolver.mavenLocalFile,
    resolvers += "conjars" at "http://conjars.org/repo",
    resolvers += "clojars" at "https://clojars.org/repo"
  )
}
```

`project/dependencies.scala`:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object Dependencies {
  val sparkVersion = "2.0.0"
  val awsVersion = "1.11.12"
  val sprayVersion = "1.3.2"
  val hiveVersion = "2.1.0"
  val hadoopVersion = "2.7.2"
  val esVersion = "2.3.2"

  val sparkCoreDependency: ModuleID = "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided"
  val sparkMLDependency: ModuleID = "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion % "provided"
  val awsDependency: ModuleID = "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % awsVersion
  val sprayJsonDependency: ModuleID = "io.spray" %% "spray-json" % sprayVersion
  val hiveExecDependency: ModuleID = "org.apache.hive" % "hive-exec" % hiveVersion % "provided"
  val hadoopCommonDependency: ModuleID = "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % hadoopVersion % "provided"
  val esHadoopDependency: ModuleID = "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-hadoop" % esVersion % "provided"
}
```

`build.sbt`:

```
import Dependencies._

lazy val utils = (project in file("utils")).
  settings(Commons.settings: _*).
  settings(
    name := "hadoop-utils",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      hiveExecDependency,
      sparkCoreDependency,
      awsDependency,
      hadoopCommonDependency,
      esHadoopDependency
    )
  )

lazy val ingestion = (project in file("ingestion")).
  settings(Commons.settings: _*).
  settings(
    name := "datascience-ingestion",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      sparkCoreDependency,
      awsDependency,
      sprayJsonDependency
    )
  ).
  dependsOn(utils)

lazy val hlda = (project in file("hlda")).
  settings(Commons.settings: _*).
  settings(
    name := "hlda",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      sparkCoreDependency,
      sparkMLDependency,
      awsDependency,
      sprayJsonDependency
    ),
    assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
      ShadeRule.rename("org.apache.http.**" -> "shadehttp.@1").inAll
    )
  )
```

When I try to compile, I get:

```
$ sbt utils/compile
[info] Loading global plugins from ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /<snip>/project
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to /<snip>/project/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/classes...
[info] Set current project to datascience-ingestion (in build file:/<snip>/)
[info] Updating {file:/<snip>/}utils...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in {file:/<snip>/}utils:
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-launcher _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.json4s:json4s-ast _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle _2.11, _2.10
[error]    com.twitter:chill _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.json4s:json4s-jackson _2.11, _2.10
[error]    com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.json4s:json4s-core _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-core _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.apache.spark:spark-network-common _2.11, _2.10
java.lang.RuntimeException: Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.apache.spark:spark-launcher, org.json4s:json4s-ast, org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle, com.twitter:chill, org.json4s:json4s-jackson, com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala, org.json4s:json4s-core, org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe, org.apache.spark:spark-core, org.apache.spark:spark-network-common
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at sbt.ConflictWarning$.processCrossVersioned(ConflictWarning.scala:46)
    at sbt.ConflictWarning$.apply(ConflictWarning.scala:32)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$69.apply(Defaults.scala:1219)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$69.apply(Defaults.scala:1216)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (utils/*:update) Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.apache.spark:spark-launcher, org.json4s:json4s-ast, org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle, com.twitter:chill, org.json4s:json4s-jackson, com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala, org.json4s:json4s-core, org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe, org.apache.spark:spark-core, org.apache.spark:spark-network-common
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed Aug 11, 2016 10:43:16 AM
```

I have even tried "hard-coding" the version suffixes. For example:

```
val sparkCoreDependency: ModuleID = "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % sparkVersion % "provided"
```

But I got the same error. This was all working before I changed only the spark and scala version numbers.

Comment: Did you try `sbt clean clean-files` prior to compilation?

Comment: Yes. Did not change anything.

Comment: You can try using https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph to see where the 2.10 dependencies come from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because [elasticsearch-hadoop 2.3.2](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hadoop/2.3.2/elasticsearch-hadoop-2.3.2.pom) depends on spark-core_2.10 and spark-sql_2.10. You probably have to use Scala 2.10 or fork elasticsearch-hadoop.